# How to import Seaborn on EC2 t2.micro instance?

Tags: seaborn

I am trying to import seaborn as sns on EC2 AWS ipython notebook.

But I am getting the following error. Please help

```
import seaborn as sns
```

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 import seaborn as sns

ImportError: No module named seaborn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may first want to download seaborn package. It is not available by default with python installation.

Use pip to download :

```
pip install seaborn
```

Additionaly, you can try installing [anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install-linux.html)

```
$ curl -O https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ chmod 777 Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
$ ./Anaconda3-4.3.1-Linux-x86_64.sh
... (Press enter/yes where ever required )
$ conda install seaborn
```

Comment: I tried installing using pip but it loading all mandatory dependent packages and then results is compilation is terminated.

Comment: Could you show what is the result of running the command and the error you are encountering ?

Comment: If the above answer helped then you can accept the answer. It helps other know if the answer is helpful or not.